# Assign image to asset in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, assign

If I manually create an image and assign a product. It works great in console:

```
p = Spree::Product.first
i = Spree::Image.create!(<create info>)

p.images << i

p.save!
```

When I try to run this in a program. It doesn't do anything. It runs as if the `p.images << i` never ran.

I tried searching, but didn't know how to search for << very well.

**Update**

If I add to the program:

```
p = Spree::Product.first
i = Spree::Image.create!(<create info>)

i = Spree::Image.find(i.id) #this line

p.images << i

p.save!
```

This works great, but i don't understand what is going on here.

Thanks in advanced!
Justin

Answer (score 0):

So this is pretty common among ORMs.

> The collection<< method adds one or more objects to the collection by
>   setting their foreign keys to the primary key of the calling model.

Per the rails tutorials: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

If you go to that page you can do ctrl+f
and search for: <<

That will give you a ton of information on this.

Also I'll recommend one more source. I like the documentation on this ORM a little better:
http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html

It's NOT active record, but it's very similar. For me, working with datamapper helped me get a better grasp of active record.

Hope that helps.